# API Endpoints - /xcomEntries/{xcom_key} - doesn't return value

Tags: airflow

**Apache Airflow version: 2.0.0**

What happened:

- Using endpoint `/dags/{dag_id}/dagRuns/{dag_run_id}/taskInstances/{task_id}/xcomEntries/{xcom_key}` I got Response Body but without value entry. Like:

```
{
  "dag_id": "string",
  "execution_date": "string",
  "key": "string",
  "task_id": "string",
  "timestamp": "string"
}
```

Instead of:

```
{
  "dag_id": "string",
  "execution_date": "string",
  "key": "string",
  "task_id": "string",
  "timestamp": "string",
  "value": "string"
}
```

The exact value by defined key exists.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed as a bug: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/13676

Will be fixed in **2.0.1** version.